# Asking user for admin password in sandboxed OSX app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm writing an app where I'd like the custom preferences window to ask for an admin password (but never store it) before allowing any changes. Up unitl now I've been using this code snippet:

```
    OSStatus status;
    AuthorizationRef authorizationRef;

    // AuthorizationCreate and pass NULL as the initial
    // AuthorizationRights set so that the AuthorizationRef gets created
    // successfully, and then later call AuthorizationCopyRights to
    // determine or extend the allowable rights.
    // http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2001/qa1172.html
    status = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authorizationRef);
    if (status != errAuthorizationSuccess)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error Creating Initial Authorization: %d", status);
        return status;
    }

    // kAuthorizationRightExecute == "system.privilege.admin"
    AuthorizationItem right = {kAuthorizationRightExecute, 0, NULL, 0};
    AuthorizationRights rights = {1, &right};
    AuthorizationFlags flags = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed | kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize | kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

    // Call AuthorizationCopyRights to determine or extend the allowable rights.
    status = AuthorizationCopyRights(authorizationRef, &rights, NULL, flags, NULL);
    if (status != errAuthorizationSuccess)
    {
        NSLog(@"Copy Rights Unsuccessful: %d", status);
    }
    return status;
```

Which worked fine, presenting a standard os password dialog asking for administrator password entry. The various controls in the preference's nib are enabled/disabled according to the returned `status`. However, now I'm trying to Sandbox the app and this code always returns `errAuthorizationDenied`. I've had a look at the doc's for the `AuthorizationCopyRights` and `AuthorizationCreate` but I can't see reference to using them in a Sandboxed environemnt.

I've tried varieties of the `AuthorizationFlags flags` but it's always the same result. Is there a way of modifying the above code to work in Sandbox, or is asking for an admin password just a no-no these days?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have looked at the docs for sandboxing and the section called [Determine Whether Your App is Suitable for Sandboxing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH4-SW6) immediately answers your question.

From the docs

> The following app behaviors are incompatible with App Sandbox:
>
> - Use of Authorization Services

Game over.

In fact, I'm not sure what you are hoping to achieve.  Why wouldn't you let the user determine their own custom preferences for the application?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - bad of me not to look there. It's a relatively trivial background app, but I do need the prefs (and a couple of other of it's tools) to be restricted to the system admin only. The regular user should only be notified of it running/not. I have an option to store an app-specific, hashed password in the userPrefs and I'll have to make do with that.

Comment: I agree, there are situations where this is a very fair requirement.  For example, let's say I want to make an app to let teachers check in on computers in a computer lab.  If no admin password is required to turn the app off, students could easily evade teacher surveillance.  (just one such example, but I think there are many use cases)

Comment: @MaxvonHippel The easy way around that is not to make your app sandboxed.  Of course, that means you can't sell it through the app store but that is not a showstopper on OS X.

Comment: I know, but I think apple should let us sandbox apps that do this using exceptions.